# Filter formula with 2 conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I am having a hard time figuring out how to get this to work on Google Sheets. I am trying to create a player pool based on the checkbox on a different tab. However, I want it to look for a checkmark, then look at the position, and then bring in the data.

Checkbox is in column A. Player position is in column H.

```
=if(and('Hitter Gameday'!A:A=true,'Hitter Gameday'!H:H="SS"),filter('Hitter Gameday'!B:X))
```

Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=iferror(filter('Hitter Gameday'!B:X, 'Hitter Gameday'!A:A=true, regexmatch('Hitter Gameday'!H:H, "C.*")))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Yes it did! Now I have, what should be the final issue to overcome. Some players have multiple positions... so instead of just having a "C" they may have a "C/1B". So what do I add for it to look for multiple text phrases? "C", "C/1B", "C/OF" just as an example.

Comment: @Ricky: I updated the formula. See if that helps?